# Google Custom Search returns 'No Results' only

Tags: search-engine, google-custom-search

I am using Google's Linked Custom Search Engines. Below is my code. But I am not able to get any results. I am trying to search a site www.penmai.com. Please find the 
http://niranjan.99k.org/wa/cref_cse.xml

```
<html>
    <head>
        <form id="cref" action="http://www.google.com/cse">
          <input type="hidden" name="cref" value="http://niranjan.99k.org/wa/cref_cse.xml" />
          <input type="text" name="q" size="40" />
          <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
        </form>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/cse/brand?form=cref"></script>
<!-- Google CSE Search Box Ends -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the location you are trying to fetch data from.. cse only works with hosted webpages and not files like .xml